# How to setup flexible box CSS through jQuery? css( display, '-moz-box') doesn't seem to work?

Tags: jquery, css

This works:

```
display: box;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
```

This also works:

```
.attr('style','display: -moz-box')
```

This doesn't :-(

```
css( display, '-moz-box')
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/TomasReichmann/K3nQg/

I am building a plugin that displays a window-like **resizeable** modal box with header that can have variable height and content, that fits inside the box and displays a scrollbar if it's content is too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing the quotes around `display`; when passing a property and a value to [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css), both must be strings:

```
.css('display', '-moz-box')
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/K3nQg/1)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
css( 'display', '-moz-box !important')
```

Comment: Just in case if he is setting display attribute somewhere else in one of his style-sheets.